# jQuery UI Autocomplete is not styled correctly

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have an autocomplete but it is not shown correctly. I let you see some screen before:
- First, the width is wrong. It's too wide! And I would like to solve it without set the width (if you see the [example on jquery-ui site](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/), the width is not set)[image]

- Second, if I have a list too long, it move over the footer and leave a big white space under the footer (in black you can see the footer, in red the autocomplete menu, and in white under the red menu the empty space that appear when I have a long list):
  [image]

Perhaps the second request make no sense because it is working correctly, but I think it is better if the footer go down the menu.

Here the css I am using:

```
.ui-menu {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    outline: none;

}
.ui-menu .ui-menu {
    position: absolute;
}
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 3px 1em 3px .4em;
    cursor: pointer;
    min-height: 0; /* support: IE7 
    /* support: IE10, see #8844 */
    list-style-image: url("data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7");
}

.ui-autocomplete {
   /* max-height: 200px;*/
    overflow-y: auto;   /* prevent horizontal scrollbar */
    overflow-x: hidden; /* add padding to account for vertical scrollbar */
    z-index:1000 !important;
    /*max-width: 173px;*/
        background-color: red;
        border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
```

Can anyone help me at least for first request? 
Thank you

Comment: setting `html { overflow: hidden }` (or body) should solve the second problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved with this css

```
.ui-autocomplete {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    cursor: default;
    background-color:#fff;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
    max-height: 200px;

    overflow-y: auto;   /* prevent horizontal scrollbar */
    overflow-x: hidden; /* add padding to account for vertical scrollbar */
    z-index:1000 !important;
}
```